# typo3: how does css work in the system

Tags: typo3

In one page, I installed a plugin called 'core', then in page->template, I put inline css, like this:

```
[global]
[globalVar= TSFE:id=159]
page {
  CSS_inlineStyle (  
.tx-core-pi1 .intro h1 {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  })
}
```

But in the front page, it is overwritten by

```
#main h1{border-bottom: 1px solid #EA9E2A;}
```

this configuration:  `#main h1` is located in this file:`fileadmin/templates/template1/styles.css`

If i change `.tx-core-pi1 .intro h1` to `#main h1` in ts setting, then it will work properly, it will override `#main h1{border-bottom: 1px solid #EA9E2A;}`, so how does css apply to front page in typo3? which has the higher priority? plugin css, inlincss...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing has nothing to do with TYPO3. It results from the CSS standard (shortened):

If multiple rules apply to the same property of an element, the rule with the more specific selector takes precedence. Since selectors containing an ID have a very high precedence, the rule containing `#main` is used. If both rules are equally specific (as happens when you change the selector of the rule from TypoScript to `#main h1`), the rule that appears later is used.

Here is an [introduction to CSS specifity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).